# How to deinit ViewControllers embedded in a TabBarController [Swift 5]

Tags: swift, automatic-ref-counting, deinit

I have got two ViewControllers encapsulated and instantiated in a TabBarController. The TabBarController is instantiated in a superordinate NavigationController.

When the NavigationController decides to go back and 'leave' the TabBarController and its two ViewControllers, the NavigationController deinit the TabBarController. The deinit method of the TabBarController is called. But I noticed, that the deinit methods of my two ViewControllers aren't called.

**Question**

How could it be, that the TabBarController can be deallocated but not the embedded ViewControllers? How does ARC work in this situation? How to force a deinit call of the embedded ViewControllers?